# How do I reduce a python (docker) image size using a multi-stage build?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

I am looking for a way to create multistage builds with python and Dockerfile:

For example, using the following images:

**1st image**: install all compile-time requirements, and install all needed python modules

**2nd image**: copy all compiled/built packages from the first image to the second, without the compilers themselves (gcc, postgers-dev, python-dev, etc..)

The final objective is to have a smaller image, running python and the python packages that I need.

In short: **how can I 'wrap' all the compiled modules** (site-packages / external libs) that were created in the first image, and **copy them in a 'clean' manner**, to the 2nd image.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this? i need to do the same

Answer (score 52, accepted):

ok so my solution is using wheel, it lets us compile on first image, create wheel files for all dependencies and install them in the second image, without installing the compilers

```
FROM python:2.7-alpine as base

RUN mkdir /svc
COPY . /svc
WORKDIR /svc

RUN apk add --update \
    postgresql-dev \
    gcc \
    musl-dev \
    linux-headers

RUN pip install wheel && pip wheel . --wheel-dir=/svc/wheels

FROM python:2.7-alpine

COPY --from=base /svc /svc

WORKDIR /svc

RUN pip install --no-index --find-links=/svc/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

You can see my answer regarding this in the following blog post

https://www.blogfoobar.com/post/2018/02/10/python-and-docker-multistage-build

Comment: This is very helpful! You still have the wheels files in the result though, in addition to their installed form. I guess using Rocker is the right solution, since Docker refuses to give us mounting during builds.

Comment: Important note - instead of /shadow_reporting/wheels it should be /srv/wheels or any other dir you copy wheels to

Comment: @gCoh Sorry if my question is trivial, but what is it the `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @philippos https://learnpython.com/blog/python-requirements-file/

Comment: This is probably a better solution than using the venv method which requires an env variable to be updated/image recreated.

Comment: Is it safe to `rm -rf /svc/wheels/` after you `pip install ... requirements.txt`?

Answer (score 18):

I recommend the approach detailed in [this article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/multi-stage-docker-python/) (section 2). He uses virtualenv so pip install stores all the python code, binaries, etc. under one folder instead of spread out all over the file system. Then it's easy to copy just that one folder to the final "production" image.  In summary:

Compile image

- Activate virtualenv in some path of your choosing.
- Prepend that path to your docker ENV. This is all virtualenv needs to function for all future docker RUN and CMD action.
- Install system dev packages and `pip install xyz` as usual.

Production image

- Copy the virtualenv folder from the Compile Image.
- Prepend the virtualenv folder to docker's PATH

Comment: I have been trying exactly the same example you mentioned, however I kept getting the following error: Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "myapp": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Comment: @philippos I'm not sure what's causing that but I would start a new SO post with more detail, assuming you can't find anything helpful via search. I don't think it has anything to do with the specific thing we're trying to solve on this page.

Comment: There's one gotcha with this method. If you already deployed the image previously and are trying to update it, you need to remove the `PATH` env and recreate the image. I use portainer which allows you to just delete the variable. I guess in docker you would need to delete and recreate the entire container (not 100% sure).

Answer (score 6):

This is a place where using a Python virtual environment inside Docker can be useful.  Copying a virtual environment normally is tricky since it needs to be the exact same filesystem path on the exact same Python build, but in Docker you can guarantee that.

(This is the same basic recipe @mpoisot describes in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61879604) and it appears in other SO answers as well.)

Say you're installing the [psycopg](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg/) PostgreSQL client library.  The extended form of this requires the Python C development library plus the PostgreSQL C client library headers; but to run it you only need the PostgreSQL C runtime library.  So here you can use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build): the first stage installs the virtual environment using the full C toolchain, and the final stage copies the built virtual environment but only includes the minimum required libraries.

A typical Dockerfile could look like:

```sh
# Name the single Python image we're using everywhere.
ARG python=python:3.10-slim

# Build stage:
FROM ${python} AS build

# Install a full C toolchain and C build-time dependencies for
# everything we're going to need.
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      build-essential \
      libpq-dev

# Create the virtual environment.
RUN python3 -m venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

# Install the Python library dependencies, including those with
# C extensions.  They'll get installed into the virtual environment.
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Final stage:
FROM ${python}

# Install the runtime-only C library dependencies we need.
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      libpq5

# Copy the virtual environment from the first stage.
COPY --from=build /venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application in.
COPY . .
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

If your application uses a [Python entry point script](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) then you can do everything in the first stage: `RUN pip install .` will copy the application into the virtual environment and create a wrapper script in `/venv/bin` for you.  In the final stage you don't need to `COPY` the application again.  Set the `CMD` to run the wrapper script out of the virtual environment, which is already at the front of the `$PATH`.

Again, note that this approach only works because it is the same Python base image in both stages, and because the virtual environment is on the exact same path.  If it is a different Python or a different container path the transplanted virtual environment may not work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I reduced 300MB by removing gcc and build-essential. My image reduced from 866MB to 555MB.

Answer (score -20):

The docs on this explain exactly how to do this.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/#before-multi-stage-builds

Basically you do exactly what you've said. The magic of multistage build feature though is that you can do this all from one dockerfile.

ie:

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```

This builds a go binary, then the next image runs the binary. The first image has all the build tools and the seccond is just a base linux machine that can run a binary.

Comment: this is a general solution and not a python specific

Comment: adapt it to what you need... get a linux image install postgresql on it or whatever build tools you need etc... This gets you the light final image you requested, you then need to use whatever the bundling system that suits you. https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html

Comment: so what exactly do you need to copy from first image to work in the second image, that is the question.. "adapt it to what you need" does not help at all