# Build a new docker image from two base images (centos and python)

Tags: python, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image based on Centos8. Within this image I want to install Python with the version 3.7.7. Such a Python image already exists in dockerhub.

How can I use both base images to build a new docker image?

```
From python:3.7.7 
# which files and foldes do I have to copy to my new docker image?

From centos:8
LABEL maintainer myself@test.com
```

If that is not possible it is the best way to build the python version from scratch [Link](https://pingchengtech.com/post/install-python-3-7-on-centos-7) - The problem with this solution is that the docker image is huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR You generally can't have on an image all there is in two images(The reason is explained below)
TL;DR List of solutions:

1. Use a base image that already is CentOS and has a Python installed, maybe  [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/python-36-centos7) image.
2. Start from CentOS image, install Python using package manager in the Dockerfile.
3. Start from CentOS image, build Python in Dockerfile.
4. Just use Python in the provided distributions.

Long Answer:
Using `FROM imagename` is equivalent of downloading a pre-built image and then adding on it the instructions in the current Dockerfile.
An image is basically a snapshot of the filesystem.
One of them is the snapshot of a container with probably a Linux distribution in place and Python installed.
The other is snapshot of the filesystem of another Linux distribution with all its stuff in place.
You just can't mix them, because the image isn't just Python. It is all Python needs to run beside a working Linux kernel and mixing them together almost certainly breaks them. because they have conflicting files and ways of running them in place.
But you can change one snapshot to make another snapshot off of it, for example you can take image of CentOS and install Python using the package manager, can then take a snapshot off of it and use it as working Docker container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That helps a Lot. If I compile python in the dockerfile - your third solution - can I then still reduce the size of the docker image? Currently my Centos Python Image is 680 MB and has tools for building python such as zlib, make etc. as well as many intermediate files

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory I would appreciate choosing it as the right answer. There are some ways to handle that, the main way for such situations is using multi-stage builds, which is building a thing in another container then copy it in your target container and use it, But doing that with Python could get complicated. You can install libs, build then clean **in one RUN** command, so the libs don't end up in the image, but if you do it multiple RUNs despite deleting, it would NOT reduce that size of the image.

Comment: @user5580578 Again I suggest you use slim images or alpine images provided in the official repos. In my experience, buster-slim image is about 300MB without your app and alpine is 70MB without your own app. Another way you can optimize the size is building your requirements that require binaries, in another image and the copy the built result in the new image and example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48714519/2099608 
A great resource for dockerizing your Python applications is the blog pythonspeed.com/docker/