# Reducing Docker Image Size without using Alpine

Tags: docker

I am currently trying to reduce my Docker Image Size (Without using Alpine, since a few dependencies wouldn't work properly for my project).

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
# install dependencies
# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends tesseract-ocr libpoppler-cpp-dev mupdf default-jre default-jdk python3-pip pkg-config && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && apt autoremove && pip3 install -r requirements.txt
#RUN pip3 install virtualenv
#RUN python3 -m virtualenv env
#RUN source env/bin/activate


EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I checked at docker hub and found the following image layers:

[image]

I came across multi-stage build using Docker but it's not much reducing the size. So, I want to know what other thing I can do to reduce the docker image size.

Current size is around **1.65GB**

I also came across building your own Docker Image but the ubuntu:latest is already 72.8 MB around so I think it should work for me.

Comment: Anything where you `apt-get install build-essential` will be huge.  [How do I reduce a python (docker) image size using a multi-stage build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543834/how-do-i-reduce-a-python-docker-image-size-using-a-multi-stage-build) discusses one approach (building wheel files in one stage, then `COPY`ing them into an image that doesn't include the C toolchain); I've also seen a virtual-environment-based approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with replacing the ubuntu base image with a debian alternative. This should not bring too much pain and allows you to have access to -slim images.

e.g.

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim
```

I also noticed you autoremove after pip install, I would advise you do this on the line you apt-install. Each layer is saved with all its content, so autoremove as soon as possible not to save it into the layer.

Comment: Thanks for responding.
But the base image is larger than what I am currently using:

    *debian                      bullseye-slim   d40a74a77bd3   2 days ago           80.4MB
    ubuntu                      latest          fb52e22af1b0   4 weeks ago          72.8MB*

Thanks for the autoremove part though.

Answer (score -1):

Not quite a straight answer, but this blog series give a lot of context and solutions about reducing images size.

[The quest for minimal docker images](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2020/02/01/quest-minimal-docker-images-part-1/)

Comment: Link only answers are not what we're after on StackOverflow. When we want to do this we usually just leave a comment.