# Installing mariaDB client efficiently inside docker

Tags: python, docker, mariadb, driver

my Python application requires the following package -> https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/

The pain for me here is that the installation of this packages requires the following build stage at my Dockerfile:

```
RUN curl -LsS https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup | sudo bash && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y mariadb-client libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
```

To make this RUN command properly work, you also need to install gcc and pkg-config, otherwise the mariadb-client can't be compiled during installation. This way of installation is kinda ugly inside docker as it massively blows up the image size due to the installation of gcc ...

How can I have these packages installed without having to install gcc ??? Are there any pre-compiled binaries I can use here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is [How do I reduce a python (docker) image size using a multi-stage build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48543834/how-do-i-reduce-a-python-docker-image-size-using-a-multi-stage-build) essentially what you're asking?  I lay out an approach in [this answer](/a/71088501) using a virtual environment; it uses PostgreSQL and not MariaDB but the overall approach will be the same.

Comment: Noo, I'm aware of multistage builds, but here we have a dependence problem between multiple software components which are required to get the mysql client installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [a multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) to build the `mysqlclient` wheel in the first stage, then copy it over to the runtime stage. This leaves `gcc` and friends only in the build stage.

You can of course do this for all of your `requirements.txt` too – `pip wheel -w /deps -r requirements.txt` or whatnot.

```
FROM python:3.12 as mysqlclient-build
RUN curl -LsS https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup | bash 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y mariadb-client libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev
RUN pip wheel -w /deps mysqlclient

FROM python:3.12
COPY --from=mysqlclient-build /deps/*.whl /deps
RUN pip install /deps/*.whl && rm -rf /deps
# ... the rest of your actual application bits
```

Depending on whether the `mysqlclient` wheel ends up statically linking the runtime `libmariadb` library, you may or may not need to also `apt-get install` that in the runtime stage.

Comment: So, I now tried your solution, but it's not working for me, I have a mysqlclient-2.2.1-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl at my mariadb_client build stage which I copy over to my base image and run:

RUN pip wheel -w /deps mysqlclient-2.2.1-cp311-cp311-linux_x86_64.whl

So far so good, but this still not magically makes "pip install mysqlclient" work...
Failing with:

Trying pkg-config --exists mysqlclient
Command 'pkg-config --exists mysqlclient' returned non-zero exit status 1.

So all in all, it appears we still need the mysql-client to be installed and by this also again gcc.

Comment: You evidently didn't do `RUN pip install /deps/*.whl`. IOW, you need to `pip install` the wheel, `pip wheel`ing it again doesn't help you much.

Comment: I did, but it simply wasn't part of my comment.

Comment: Despite that I can install the pre-compiled wheel I don't get a connection to my mariaDB instance anymore, so there has to be another issue, it appears it's not only just about the mysqlclient packge from Pypi

Comment: You don't need to do `pip install mysqlclient` if you just install the wheel. If `mysqlclient` is part of other dependencies, you can also use `pip install --find-links=/deps -r requirements.txt` so pip will prefer the pre-built wheel directory. As for "don't get a connection", that I can't help much with without seeing the error. (Recall, though, that `127.0.0.1` is not the host machine within a Docker container.)

Comment: Yes, I just saw that the connection issue comes from another dep. I have mysqladmin for a pre-check in use here, I need to refactor this... Thanks so far for your help, I will mark this question as answered

Answer (score 0):

Here is also my final solution:

1. Build the mysqlclient wheel

```
    FROM python:3.11.7-slim-bookworm as mariadb_client_builder
    
    # Install build dependencies
    RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y gcc pkg-config curl
    
    RUN curl -LsS https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup | bash && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev
    
    # Install mysqlclient, building it into a wheel file
    RUN pip wheel --no-cache-dir --wheel-dir=/usr/src/app/wheels mysqlclient
```

2. Using the wheel at your final image:

```
    COPY --from=mariadb_client_builder /usr/src/app/wheels /wheels

    # Setup virtualenv
    RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
        pip install setuptools virtualenv && \
        python -m virtualenv /venv && \
        . /venv/bin/activate && \
        pip install --no-cache /wheels/* && \
        pip install -r requirements.txt && \
        deactivate
```

Make sure mysqlclient isn't part of your requirements.txt anymore, as we installed it directly from the pre-compiled wheel into our venv.

Attention, the Pypi mysqlclient also needs the libmariadb-dev package to be installed in your final image, so you are absolutely required to also do the following in your final image:

```
RUN curl -LsS https://r.mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb_repo_setup | bash && \
        apt-get update && \
        apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev
```

You basically need the libmariadb-dev package for building the wheel and also to later connect with your final image to the mariadb/mysql instance.

Comment: The dev package is not needed in the runtime image, but the runtime package (libmariadb) is. Additionally, as I mentioned in my comment, you don't need to cull mysqlclient from your requirements if you use `--find-links` to tell Pip you have local wheels.